# MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here are some lines of code... I have another application running that is setup exactly the same and I am having no issues.

`app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`

**Here is the link tag**

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/css/app.css">`

**It does the same with this img tag**

`<img src="/app/img/SCS-NewLogo_donl.svg" height="65px" width="350px" id="sc-logo">`

I am not sure why, but it seems to be sending the file as HTML. Usually this means the file is not found on the server, but I checked myself and confirmed that it is.

**Full file**

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./lib/config');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const URLS = require('./lib/URLS.js');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9005;
const ENV = config.ENV || 'TEST';
const SERVER = config.SERVER;
const app = express();

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.all(/^\/apps$/, function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/apps/job-search');
});

app.get('/apps/job-search', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/search');
});

app.post('/apps/job-search/send-input', (req, res) => {

  // Send data to API server which will handle DB query...
  axios.get(URLS.GatherSearchResults)
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp.data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('App is listening on port ' + PORT + ' on server ' + SERVER + '...');
});
```

**Directory Structure**

```
Root
  public
     css
     img
  views
     pages
       search.ejs
     partials
       header.ejs
       footer.ejs
   app.js
```

Comment: Can you share your entire express file (server.js or similar)? Are you using any middleware before the static line?

Comment: Added full file.

Comment: May we see your directory structure please?

Comment: Updated with directory structure

Answer (score 0):

I thinkk I see your issue. After declaring the route `/app` as static, you remap it to `'/apps/job-search'` several lines later.

Change the static line to `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` and your links in the HTML file should start wit `/css` and `/img` etc.

Verify that by trying to open one of your existing links, and seeing what content you're currently serving (my guess - it'd be whatever is at `'/apps/job-search'`).

Comment: The reason I have to use "/apps" as static is because there are multiple different apps running on the server. So for example... website.com has multiple different things such as website.com/client or website.com/employee. If I don't use that, it will pull css files from the wrong directory. This app runs on website.com/apps/job-search

Comment: Turns out this lead me to fixing the issue. The base route is /apps/job-search. I went ahead and adjusted the static route to apps/job-search and changed the actual home route to be apps/job-search/search and it fixed the issue.